# faster parsing a file for all list elements and apending into new files based on the list elements

Tags: python, file, parsing, list, append

I am trying to parse a log file with threadids in every like. There could be any number of threads that can be configured. All threads write to the same log file and I am parsing the log file and creating new files specific for each thread in order to check them later.
Below I am capturing the threadids in a list.
The below code is doing the job but I feel this is not efficient. Can there be anything faster ?.

```
sThdiD = ["abc", "cde\"efg"]
folderpath = "newdir"
os.system("mkdir " + folderpath)
for line in open(filetoopen):
    for i in sThdiD:
        if i in line:
            open(folderpath+"/"+i+".log","a+").write(line)
```

Comment: Keep a list of open files instead of calling open each time in the loop

Comment: How many threadids? A few thousand open files at the same time should not really be a problem (if the machine is not otherwise occupied).

Comment: use subprocess.call not os.system; it's safer. Also you should really change `open(folderpath+"/"+i+".log","a+").write(line)` to `open(os.path.join(folderpath, i + ".log"),"a+").write(line)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can fit the whole log file into memory, I'd keep a dictionary mapping thread IDs to lines written by that thread, and then write out whole files at the end.

```
thread_map = {}  # keys are thread IDs; values are lists of log lines
for line in open(filetoopen):
  for i in sThdiD:
    if i in line:
      if i not in thread_map:
        thread_map[i] = []
      thread_map[i].append(line)

for key in thread_map:
  f = open(folderpath+"/"+key+".log", "w")
  for line in thread_map[key]:
    f.write(line)
  f.close()
```

If you can't keep the whole log file in memory, try a multipass solution in which you write each file one at a time.

```
in_file = open(filetoopen)
for i in sThdiD:
  in_file.seek(0)  # Reset the file to read from the beginning.
  out_file = open(folderpath+"/"+i+".log", "w")
  for line in in_file:
    if i in line:
      out_file.write(line)
  out_file.close()
in_file.close()
```